# What languages are spoken by the aborigines, and where are those villages?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, tracks

In the film 'Tracks', Robyn Davidson passes along a number of villages.  In one of the villages, a group of women do singing/dancing for her.  In another, someone accompanies her through sacred land.

The film titles mention the names of the villages in the acknowledgements, but this information does not appear to be listed on IMDB or on the films official website.  What villages/tribes were featured in the film, and what language do they speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm no expert on the subject, nor am I familiar with these places. This site discusses movies & TV, after all, not geography and anthropology. The information below is gleaned from the film's end credits, Wikipedia and a few extracts from Robyn Davidson's original account of her journey, so it's probably not 100%. Consider this a placeholder until someone more knowledgeable comes along.

First of all, the main language in most of the places mentioned below (and that the real Davidson used in many of the places she visited) is [Pitjantjatjara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitjantjatjara_language), unless specified otherwise, but the film may have contained many local dialects.

The communities thanked in the *Tracks* credits:

- **Anangu Pitjantjatjara Yankunytjatjara**. This is a pretty vast area, so if you're looking for something more specific, the real Davidson mentions that she visited [Pipalyatjara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipalyatjara,_South_Australia) there.
- [Kaltukatjara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaltukatjara), AKA Docker River. The real Davidson visited this place as well.
- [Mutitjulu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutitjulu), in the Northern Territory.
- [Adnyamathanha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adnyamathanha) (which is also their traditional language).
- [Ngaanyatjarra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngaanyatjarra) (which is also their traditional language).

A couple of other places that the real Davidson visited but that might not have appeared in the film:

- [Areyonga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areyonga,_Northern_Territory), in the Northern Territory
- [Wingellina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingellina,_Western_Australia), in Western Australia

You can see Robyn Davidson's original route [in this picture](http://najhaus.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/img_2403.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the film end credits.  I saw those but I didn't remember or write down the places, and couldn't find the same information elsewhere.  Do you have a particular source for the end credits, or did you happen to have the movie at hand?

Comment: Yes, this is based on the movie's actual end credits (though I don't have it at hand, I'm afraid).